# Sending post to PHP from Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to send data from an android application to PHP using POST the PHP will forward it to MySQL database and give respond. the application is crashing. can somebody please assist me.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(login_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("p", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p, "UTF-8") + "&" +
            URLEncoder.encode("q", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8") + "&" +
            URLEncoder.encode("r", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(r, "UTF-8") + "&" +
            URLEncoder.encode("s", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        InputStream inputstream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream, "iso-8859-1"));
        String result = "";
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputstream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error message that gets output when the crash occurs?

Comment: `the application is crashing` . Post the crash report

Answer (score 0):

**Check your thread !!**

You are run http request on UI thread, So you get error.

Try create a new Thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("p","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(p,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("q","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(q,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("r","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(r,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("s","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(s,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputstream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputstream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```